# Mostrar solo primer párrafo <p> con MySQL o PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Al realizar una consulta en MySQL con PHP obtengo como resultado lo siguiente:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipiscing elit ut per.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipiscing elit ut per.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipiscing elit ut per.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipiscing elit ut per.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipiscing elit ut per.</p>
```

Varios párrafos con su respectiva etiqueta HTML `<p>`

Necesito mostrar en un `<div>` solo el primer párrafo `<p>` y en otro `<div>` los párrafos restantes.

Algo como esto:

```
<div class="sumario">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipiscing elit ut per.</p>
</div>
<div class="cuerpo">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipiscing elit ut per.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipiscing elit ut per.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipiscing elit ut per.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipiscing elit ut per.</p>
</div>
```

Hasta el momento lo único que se me ha ocurrido es hacer lo siguiente para el sumario:

`<?php echo substr(strip_tags($body, '<p>'), 0, 250); ?>`

Comment: ¿Nos mostrarías lo que has intentado al momento por favor?

Comment: La verdad no se como hacerlo, lo único que se me ocurrió fue hacer esto `<?php echo substr(strip_tags($body, '<p>'), 0, 250); ?>` para ponerlo en el sumario.

Comment: Es un buen punto de arranque y le dará mejor recibimiento a tu pregunta, edita y colócalo aunque solo sea eso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomendación:

Pues puedes tratarlo con JS puro, de esta forma no mezclas código de backend (PHP) con el uso de etiquetas de HTML:

- Obtienes todos los párrafos y los almacenas en una variable por medio de `querySelectorAll`
- Como en esa variable tienes un *nodeList* puedes iterar los elementos o indicar el acceso por medio de su índice o posición
- Declaras 2 clases a nivel de CSS una por cada posible escenario
- Dentro del `foreach` asignamos la clase a cada elemento
- Para resetear y asignar una clase distinta al primer elemento simplemente indicamos su posición o índice y le damos la clase deseada

> Con lo anterior:

- El primer párrafo tendrá la clase **`.primero`** y será de color rojo
- El resto de párrafos tendrá la clase **`.segundo`** y serán de color verde

**EJEMPLO**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Código</title>
      <style>
        .primero {
          color: red;
        }
        .segundo {
          color: green; 
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam animi tempore maxime deserunt architecto. Pariatur odit amet laudantium, commodi aut temporibus inventore mollitia iusto sapiente nemo sequi maiores, ut, vel.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam animi tempore maxime deserunt architecto. Pariatur odit amet laudantium, commodi aut temporibus inventore mollitia iusto sapiente nemo sequi maiores, ut, vel.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam animi tempore maxime deserunt architecto. Pariatur odit amet laudantium, commodi aut temporibus inventore mollitia iusto sapiente nemo sequi maiores, ut, vel.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam animi tempore maxime deserunt architecto. Pariatur odit amet laudantium, commodi aut temporibus inventore mollitia iusto sapiente nemo sequi maiores, ut, vel.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam animi tempore maxime deserunt architecto. Pariatur odit amet laudantium, commodi aut temporibus inventore mollitia iusto sapiente nemo sequi maiores, ut, vel.
    </p>
    <script>
        let parrafos = document.querySelectorAll("p")
        
        
        parrafos.forEach((elemento) => {
            elemento.setAttribute("class", "segundo")
        })
        parrafos[0].setAttribute("class", "primero")
        
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Guiándome de la respuesta que me dio @BetaM, hice lo siguiente:

Como tengo dos `<div>`

```
<div id="sumario"></div>
<div id="cuerpo"></div>`
```

Primero imprimo todo en el `<div id="cuerpo">` y después con jQuery muevo el primer párrafo a `<div id="sumario">`:

```
var body = $("#cuerpo p");

$.each(body, function() {
  $('#sumario').append(body[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Busca la primera etiqueta de cierre de párrafo para obtener el sumario y, desde ahí, obtienes el cuerpo:

```
<?php

$html = <<<EOT
<p>Primer párrafo: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipiscing elit ut per.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipiscing elit ut per.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipiscing elit ut per.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipiscing elit ut per.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipiscing elit ut per.</p>
EOT;

// Obtener posición de primer cierre de párrafo
// Y agregar 5 (1 para posición) para incluir la etiqueta completa (4)
$cuenta = mb_strpos($html, '</p>') + 5;

// Obtener primer párrafo
$sumario = mb_substr($html, 0, $cuenta);

// Obtener resto del texto
$cuerpo = mb_substr($html, $cuenta + 1);

echo <<<EOT
<div class="sumario">
    $sumario
</div>
<div class="cuerpo">
    $cuerpo
</div>
EOT;
```

**Nota:** Estoy usando la estructura [HEREDOC](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) para crear y mostrar cadenas.

Comment: La longitud de los párrafos puede cambiar, no siempre serán 5, ¿como se hace en ese caso?

Comment: @JoseDarioCorrea, tal vez tu pregunta es por ese + 5, que no tiene que ver con la cantidad de párrafos, sino con la longitud de la cadena hasta el cierre del primer párrafo. Funciona desde 2 hasta una cantidad infinita de párrafos.